# Unique_ptr containers or unique_ptr elements

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

What would be the difference between a `unique_ptr<list<Struct>>` and a `list<unique_ptr<Struct>>`? Will `list<unique_ptr<Struct>>` result in the memory for the elements to be automatically managed as well?

Comment: The first one is a pointer to a list, the second is a list of pointers. The second is commonly used in case of polymorphic objects (is `Struct` a base class?), the first is strange.

Comment: Yea I understand that part. What I'm mainly concerned about is the way memory allocation works in both the cases.Will the first one allocate elements on the stack or the heap? The second one is pretty obvious, the elements are on the heap, the list management info is on the stack. What about the first?

Comment: @SidharthMudgal: Both will allocate elements on the heap; that's what standard containers do. In the first case, the list structure itself is also on the heap, which is weird. In the second, each heap-allocated element is a pointer to a further heap-allocated object. Unless you need that extra indirection for some reason (like polymorphism), it should be `list<Struct>`. Or more likely `vector<Struct>`.

Comment: stop using `std::list` until you know what you are doing.  It is a horrible default container.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Wouldn't `list<Struct>` create copies of the element every time I try to insert an element or retrieve one?

Comment: @yakk why is vector better than list? Doesn't vector perform reallocation as it grows?

Comment: @SidharthMudgal: Not if you retrieve one, unless you explicitly copy it rather than using the reference you get when accessing it. Not if you insert one, if you use `emplace` rather than `insert`, or if it's movable, or if you insert a temporary and the compiler elides the copy. And, unless the type is huge or complicated, copying will be faster than memory allocation.

Comment: @SidharthMudgal: Vectors do reallocate as they grow; but lists need to allocate each element individually, and are slower to iterate over. Vectors tend to be faster than other sequence containers in most situations; you should use them unless you identify a good reason to prefer another. And even then, measure to be sure - cache locality can make them surprisingly fast even for operations like erasing in the middle that you'd expect to be slow.

Answer (score 2):

Saying `unique_ptr<>` is like saying `*` but with the added benefit of automatic deletion.

The difference between `unique_ptr<list<Struct>>` and `list<unique_ptr<Struct>>` is exactly the same as the difference between `list<Struct>*` and `list<Struct*>`. That is, one is a pointer to a `list` of `Struct`, and the other is a `list` of pointers to `Struct`. This is a rather obviously major difference.

The `list` type manages its own contents, in as much that it allocates memory for the list nodes that hold what you put in the `<>`. So a node in a `list<Struct>` holds a Struct object directly. But a node in a `list<Struct*>` holds only the pointer to the struct.

By logical extension, nodes in `list<unique_ptr<Struct>>` hold a `unique_ptr<Struct>`, which points to a Struct that has been allocated separately. Conversely, a `unique_ptr<list<Struct>>` is a pointer to a `list` whose nodes are directly-held `Struct`s.

The management of the contents of the `list` do not, and **can not** be handled by a pointer that wraps it. This is a confusion of where management is performed: `list` manages its contents - a list - directly, and `unique_ptr` manages its contents - a raw pointer - directly, and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

- The obvious difference is that you have to define `list<unique_ptr<Struct>>` at the point of construction, whereas when you construct `unique_ptr<list<Struct>>` it can just be a `nullptr`
- `list<unique_ptr<Struct>>` has an negligible overhead of storing all the pointers
- `unique_ptr<list<Struct>>` would have an overhead when fetching any members

Both store data on the heap and `unique_ptr<list<Struct>>` is a little smaller on the stack.